# Make C-v and M-v smoother

Tags: scrolling

Trying to mirror my neovim setup in emacs I haven't found a way to make `C-v` and `M-v` scroll smoothly, i.e., line by line. Most solutions I looked at improve mouse and point scrolling, but not the before-mentioned shortcuts. Do I miss something?

Comment: There is `scroll-up/down-line`: they are not bound to keys, but you can do that yourself. Not sure whether they are what you are looking for however.

Comment: @NickD I want to replicate [this](https://github.com/karb94/neoscroll.nvim) motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a way to make C-v and M-v scroll smoothly, i.e. one line at a time.

Maybe you can see [5.44 How can I force Emacs to **scroll only one line** when I move past the bottom of the screen?](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Scrolling-only-one-line.html):

> Customize the `scroll-conservatively` variable with `M-x customize-variable RET scroll-conservatively RET` and set it to a large value like, say, 10000. For an explanation of what this means, see [Auto Scrolling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Scrolling.html#Auto-Scrolling) in The GNU Emacs Manual.
>
> Alternatively, use the following Lisp form in your `.emacs`:
>
> ```
> (setq scroll-conservatively most-positive-fixnum)
> ```

It will change the behaviors of `C-p` and `C-n`.  If you consist on changing the behaviors of `C-v` and `M-v`, bind the corresponding function (the function bound to `C-p` and the function bound to `C-n`) to `M-v` or `C-v`.  (Not recommended, because `C-v` and `M-v` are there for you to move faster.)

---

Update:

Maybe you want this:

```lisp
;; C-v
(progn
  ;; unbind `scroll-up-command` from `C-v`
  (global-unset-key [?\C-v])
  ;; bind the function you want to `C-v`
  (global-set-key [?\C-v]
    #'(lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((number-of-lines 15) ; scroll N lines
              (seconds/line 0.05)) ; spend N seconds scrolling one line
          ;; execute what you want:
          ;; “one line at a time”  
          (dotimes (_ number-of-lines)
            ;; Scroll up 1 line,
            ;; but the cursor moves on the screen too.
            (scroll-up-line)
            ;; Move the cursor down 1 line so that
            ;; the cursor doesn't appear to have changed position.
            (next-line)
            (redisplay)
            (sleep-for seconds/line))))))
```

```lisp
;; M-v is similar
(progn
  (global-unset-key [?\M-v])
  (global-set-key [?\M-v]
    #'(lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((number-of-lines 15)
              (seconds/line 0.05))
          (dotimes (_ number-of-lines)
            (scroll-down-line)
            (previous-line)
            (redisplay)
            (sleep-for seconds/line))))))
```

Comment: Seems like my wording has confused you. Scrolling with point near border can be made smoother, but I want C-v to have an animation instead of a sudden jump. Again, [this](https://github.com/karb94/neoscroll.nvim) kind of motion is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: @Trashbin2019np: The answer is updated; hope it helps you :-) I'll explain the details of the code at my leisure, but you can test it for yourself and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: that's really nice! Thank you.